# Rstudio calls source() when saving script

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using Rstudio on my Mac OS 10.9.2. It was fine until I installed the new version 98.778. Whenever I try to save my script. It automatically calls source("myscript.R") for me, which is very annoying. I then re-installed the previous version, 98.501. The problem is still there. Anyone knows how to stop it?

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Are you sure "Source on save" box is unchecked?

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! Now I feel like an idiot. I knew there was some sort of setting and explored everything but didn't see this box.

Comment: Thanks! But why one could need that setting? Are there reasonable use cases?

Answer (score 10):

You probably have the "source on save" checkbox ticked (next to the save icon on the left hand side in the code editor, not for saving the Rproject) which does this. (Untick it to turn it off)

http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/using/source