# Rstudio randomly & automatically runs source() function, loses most assigned variables from environment

Tags: r, rstudio, environment

I have quite a long script in RStudio.

A few times an hour, seemingly randomly, the console will print (names changed for security reasons):

```
source('~/R/Projects/thisproject/thisRscript.R', encoding = 'UTF-8')
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  .default = col_logical(),
  var0 = col_double(),
  var1 = col_character(),
  var2 = col_character(),
  var3 = col_double(),
  var4 = col_double(),
  var5 = col_double(),
 # ... with 1363 more columns)
See spec(...) for full column specifications.
```

Then all but a handful of variables (the ones I created near the top of the script, potentially they might be the ones that were present when I accidentally saved the "workspace image" a few days ago) will disappear from the environment and I'll have to rerun the script again to generate them.

Anyone know why it is doing this or how to get it to stop? Could it be a RAM issue? (I am currently at 85% RAM utilisation and have ordered more, but if it is a different issue I would like to debug it in advance.)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had a similar issue today. I solved it by unchecking the "source on save" option in RStudio.

See here, also: [Rstudio calls source() when saving script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074692/rstudio-calls-source-when-saving-script)

[image]