# Trying to save R script instead executes whole code

Tags: r, rstudio, geospatial

Woke up to a weird and new problem. For just one of my scripts, pressing CTRL+S to save is interpreted as SHIFT+CTRL+S and saves while also sourcing the active file (i.e. running the entire thing). Pressing the save button manually in RStudio has the same effect. This is new behavior even within this script, and I'm not finding any information elsewhere on what in my script could be causing the problem. I've updated R, RStudio, and a number of packages with no effect. I don't get any error messages, but saving with CTRL+S constantly is a very instinctive part of my workflow — any idea what's messing it up?

Here's my session info:

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.4

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rgdal_1.5-23       rJava_1.0-4        rgeos_0.5-5        dismo_1.3-3       
 [5] raster_3.4-13      mapdata_2.3.0      maps_3.3.0         maptools_1.1-1    
 [9] sp_1.4-5           ggx_0.1.1          ggridges_0.5.3     RColorBrewer_1.1-2
[13] ggsci_2.9          ggpubr_0.4.0       forcats_0.5.1      stringr_1.4.0     
[17] dplyr_1.0.7        purrr_0.3.4        readr_1.4.0        tidyr_1.1.3       
[21] tibble_3.1.2       ggplot2_3.3.5      tidyverse_1.3.1   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6        lubridate_1.7.10  lattice_0.20-44   assertthat_0.2.1 
 [5] utf8_1.2.1        R6_2.5.0          cellranger_1.1.0  plyr_1.8.6       
 [9] backports_1.2.1   reprex_2.0.0      httr_1.4.2        pillar_1.6.1     
[13] rlang_0.4.11      curl_4.3.2        readxl_1.3.1      rstudioapi_0.13  
[17] data.table_1.14.0 car_3.0-11        foreign_0.8-81    munsell_0.5.0    
[21] broom_0.7.8       compiler_4.1.0    modelr_0.1.8      pkgconfig_2.0.3  
[25] tidyselect_1.1.1  codetools_0.2-18  rio_0.5.27        fansi_0.5.0      
[29] crayon_1.4.1      dbplyr_2.1.1      withr_2.4.2       grid_4.1.0       
[33] jsonlite_1.7.2    gtable_0.3.0      lifecycle_1.0.0   DBI_1.1.1        
[37] magrittr_2.0.1    scales_1.1.1      zip_2.2.0         cli_2.5.0        
[41] stringi_1.6.2     carData_3.0-4     ggsignif_0.6.2    fs_1.5.0         
[45] xml2_1.3.2        ellipsis_0.3.2    generics_0.1.0    vctrs_0.3.8      
[49] openxlsx_4.2.4    tools_4.1.0       glue_1.4.2        hms_1.1.0        
[53] abind_1.4-5       colorspace_2.0-2  rstatix_0.7.0     rvest_1.0.0      
[57] haven_2.4.1
```

And here's  my script. The gist is that I have a dataframe of coordinates for 42 species, and for each species, I need to only sample one point within each 1 km2 grid cell. I added the loop today so I'm guessing that might be what triggered it?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggsci)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggridges)
library(ggx)
library(maptools)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(dismo)
library(rgeos)
library(rJava)
library(raster) 
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

# read in full dataset of all distributions
data <- read.csv("final_dists_ALL_20Apr2021.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",",
                 na.strings = "")
data$species <- as.factor(data$species)
data$coordinateUncertaintyInMeters <- as.numeric(data$coordinateUncertaintyInMeters)

#### TEST #####

# make a test subset for costaricanum
test <- data %>% filter(species == "costaricanum" & 
(coordinateUncertaintyInMeters <= 1000 | is.na(coordinateUncertaintyInMeters)))

# turn coordinates into SpatialPointsDataFrame object
coordinates(test) <- ~ decimalLongitude + decimalLatitude

# create a RasterLayer with the extent of the study area
r <- raster(test)

# set the resolution of the cells to 1 km
res(r) <- 0.00001

# expand (extend) the extent of the RasterLayer a little
r <- extend(r, extent(r) + 1)

# sample
test_sample <- gridSample(test, r, n = 1)

# attach data info to subsample coords
test <- data %>% filter(species == "costaricanum")

test_sample <- data.frame(test_sample)

sample <- left_join(test_sample, test, by = c("decimalLongitude" = "decimalLongitude",
                                              "decimalLatitude" = "decimalLatitude"))

sample <- sample %>% distinct(decimalLongitude, decimalLatitude, .keep_all = TRUE)

##### LOOP #####

species_list <- levels(data$species)

for (i in 1:length(species_list)) {
  
  test <- data %>% filter(species == species_list[i] & 
   (coordinateUncertaintyInMeters <= 1000 | is.na(coordinateUncertaintyInMeters)))
  
  coordinates(test) <- ~ decimalLongitude + decimalLatitude

  r <- raster(test)
  res(r) <- 0.00001
  r <- extend(r, extent(r) + 1)

  test_sample <- gridSample(test, r, n = 1)
  
  test <- data %>% filter(species == species_list[i])
  test_sample <- data.frame(test_sample)
  sample <- left_join(test_sample, test, 
                      by = c("decimalLongitude" = "decimalLongitude",
                             "decimalLatitude" = "decimalLatitude"))
  
  sample <- sample %>% distinct(decimalLongitude, decimalLatitude, .keep_all = TRUE)
  
  write.csv(sample, paste0("1km_sub_", species_list[i], ".csv"), row.names = F)
  
}
```

Comment: So you're saying with this script and this script only open in RStudio the code is automatically re-run every time you save the script either with keyboard shortcuts or UI buttons? What exactly is being shown in the console? Do you have the "Source On Save" checkbox ticked? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074692/rstudio-calls-source-when-saving-script

Comment: I absolutely do have "Source on Save" checked, thank you!! That seems to have fixed it.